# addEventListener listener not able to access other methods

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have added a click event handler on a particular template like this:

```
let tableFilter = this.template.querySelector('.' + strDataTableTargetId + '_filter');
tableFilter.addEventListener('click',  this.handleCustomFilterEvents);

handleCustomFilterEvents(objEvent){
    if (objEvent !== undefined && objEvent !== null && objEvent.target !== undefined && objEvent.target !== null &&
        objEvent.target.classList !== undefined && objEvent.target.classList !== null){
        if(objEvent.target.classList.contains('addFilterAnchor')){
            this.addFilterRow(this.strTableClass); //Not able to access addFilterRow method
        }
    }
}
```

But still I am not able to access `addFilterRow` method.

I tried accessing like this :

```
tableFilter.addEventListener('click',  () => this.handleCustomFilterEvents);
```

But then the handler isn't even getting invoked.

Any thing I am missing?

**Update (Answer)**

I forgot to pass event, that is why it was not working with `=>`
This works:

`tableFilter.addEventListener('click',  (event) => this.handleCustomFilterEvents(event));`

Comment: Before ```this.addFilterRow(this.strTableClass);``` can you check if   ```objEvent.target.classList``` exist and then contains ```addFilterAnchor```?

Comment: Yes its available, basically I think its context changes that is why I am not able to access, but even after trying with empty constructor it does not work.

Comment: Git it : `tableFilter.addEventListener('click',  (event) => this.handleCustomFilterEvents(event));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to pass event, that is why it was not working with `=>` This works:

```
tableFilter.addEventListener('click',  (event) => this.handleCustomFilterEvents(event));


handleCustomFilterEvents(objEvent){
    if (objEvent !== undefined && objEvent !== null && objEvent.target !== undefined && objEvent.target !== null &&
        objEvent.target.classList !== undefined && objEvent.target.classList !== null){
        if(objEvent.target.classList.contains('addFilterAnchor')){
            this.addFilterRow(this.strTableClass); //Here I am able to access addFilterRow method
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer -- just use an arrow function, and you can call any other functions/methods in the class with the key word "this" INSIDE that arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem with your code is the function call doesn't get context of this properly.

```js
tableFilter.addEventListener('click',  () => this.handleCustomFilterEvents);
```

---

Apart from [fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function to pass the context of `this`:

```js
tableFilter.addEventListener('click',  this.handleCustomFilterEvents.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks @Raul, but in LWC we should not be using `bind` as its an anti pattern and results in memory leaks. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_handling